# Android predictive back compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I enabled `android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"` in the AndroidManifest and in the device developer options, but the animation works only for activities. I can't get it to work for Compose screens. Has anyone been able to achieve this?

I want to make it to work also for compose screens, not only for activities and fragments

Answer (score 4):

In the video ["Basics for System Back"](https://youtu.be/Elpqr5xpLxQ?t=787) at 13:07, the presenter seems to suggest that back previews (aka the peak animation) is not supported yet when using Jetpack Compose or Fragment navigation.

I believe only the back to home gesture animation is possible for Jetpack Compose or Fragment-based apps.

It's frustrating that this is buried deep at the end of a video, and not in easily indexable, and easily update-able text based documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Add support for predictive back animations

> When using the system back APIs, you can opt in to receive in-app
> animations and support custom transitions.

[Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/support-animations)